# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Text

Tags: python, css, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter

from tkinter import *

import random

import datetime


root=tkinter.Tk()

root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")

root.title("Management System")

root.configure(background ='black')




top = Frame(root, width = 1500, height = 150, bd=10, relief="raise")
top.pack(side=TOP)


f1 = Frame(root, width = 900, height = 650, bd=8, relief="raise")
f1.pack(side=LEFT)


f2= Frame(root, width = 400, height = 650, bd=8, relief="raise")
f2.pack(side=RIGHT)

label = Label(top, font=('arial', 93, 'bold'), text="Employee Management System", bd=10)
label.grid (row=0, column=0)

t= Text(f1, height = 2, width=30,font=('arial', 20, 'bold') )
t.pack()

t.insert(END, "Name:")

**f = open('tempfile.txt','w')**

**f.write(Text)**

**f.close()**
```

everything works except the write to file bit.

Comment: do you mean `t` instead of `Text`?

Comment: I assumed I would have to use 't' but when I use that it gives the same error as well

Comment: @user3080953 Using `t` would lead to another error, as `type(t).__name__ == 'str'` returns _`False`_ as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Text` is a class in [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) (which you're importing using a wildcard import as in the module's attributes occupy the main namespace directly without dereferencing first), while the `write` method accepts `str` object, not a '`Text`-class' object.

You must have meant:

```
f.write(t.get('1.0', 'end-1c'))
```

which first returns the entire text in the `Text` object as a *`string`*, then writes that string to file, `f`.

Comment: Thanks! but im trying to make it save the input? rather than the entire thing

Comment: @SavielMonzac What is _"the input"_?

Comment: where its says "t.insert(END, "Name:")" the user would have to input a supposed name and thats the bit that I want to store

Comment: @SavielMonzac It also matters _when_ you want to store an input widget's value. Nonetheless, that would be _another_ question, which there are at least tens of in [so].